# How to use HTML tags in email?

Tags: emails, theming

I have a triggered rule, when a content is Published the author receives email.
I want to show my logo in the email but so far I could not find how to do that.
Any help appreciated?

I wrote this in email message body, but instead of an image, I see only HTML text.

```
<img src="http://www.vragenenislam.com/misc/logomuz.png" alt="Vragen en Islam" />
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Mime Mail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail); that should do the trick.

> This is a Mime Mail component module (for use by other modules).
>
> - It permits users to recieve HTML email and can be used by other modules. The mail functionality accepts an HTML message body, mime-endcodes it and sends it.
> - If the HTML has embedded graphics, these graphics are MIME-encoded and included as a message attachment.
> - Adopts your site's style by automatically including your theme's stylesheet files in a themeable HTML message format
> - If the recipient's preference is available and they prefer plaintext, the HTML will be converted to plain text and sent as-is. Otherwise, the email will be sent in themeable HTML with a plaintext alternative.
> - Allows you to theme messages with a specific mailkey.
> - Converts CSS styles into inline style attributes.
> - Provides simple system actions and Rules actions to send HTML email with embedded images and attachments.

Comment: Thanks a lot Reece, I adjust my Triggered email contents by adding HTML tags but I cant find the email that I receive from Contact Form, do you know where that is?

Answer (score 1):

Mimemail module use mimemail-message.tpl.php template file to format email messages. so you can control the html and CSS form this place. If you want to send a logo, you can include the html of your logo in your version of mimemail-message.tpl.php.

here is a documentation about how to theming HTML Mail sent through Mime Mail: http://drupal.org/node/958146, follow this guide to create your own template to insert your logo, but in few words you can use a copy of mimemail-message.tpl.php file (located in modules/mimemail/theme directory) into your default theme's folder, and change your html, adding your logo in the body of the template, inside the `<div id="main">`

```
...
      <div id="main">
      <img src="http://www.vragenenislam.com/misc/logomuz.png" alt="Vragen en Islam" />
        <?php print $body ?>
      </div>
...
```

Also you can add the html that you want, according recommendations located in documentation.